# VB.NET SQL Query failing. Must declare Scalar but its already delcated

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I havent used VB.NET in a long time, last time I coded in VB, it was VB6. Gosh, I miss the good old days. Anyhow, trying to run a query on the database. My code is as follows:

```
    'Create a Connection object.
    myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dwt-monitor;Trusted_Connection=True;")

    'Create a Command object.

    myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
    myCmd.CommandText = "select log_time as [Log Time], log_name as [Log Name], log_desc as [Log Description], type_name as [Log Type] from log as log
    left join log_type as lot on log.log_id=lot.type_id where type_name= @variable"
    myConn.Open()
    myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", type)
    myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd.CommandText, myConn.ConnectionString)
    Dim table As New DataTable()


    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    dataAdapter.Fill(table)

    dgvHardwareLog.DataSource = table
    myConn.Close()
```

I am getting this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable
>   "@variable"

can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Iam Adding the value. But, alas, something isnt correct.

Thanks :)

Comment: Apologies. That should say "declared" in the header.

Comment: at which line did you get error? myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() or dataadapter.Fill?

Comment: At the dataadapter.fill

Comment: I think due to the mixing of data access (ie, command and dataadapter) you've defined the parameter for the command but not for the dataadapter. `dataadapter.selectcommand.parameters.addwithvalue....` try that. but I would get rid of the command method since you seem to want to just fill a datatable.

Comment: Did you actually declare the variable '@variable'?

Answer (score 2):

Try chnging the following line:

```
Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd.CommandText, myConn.ConnectionString)
```

With the following, where the **command** is being passed instead of just the **command text**. In addition, remove the **myConn.ConnectionString**:

```
Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd)
```

Also, you can remove the following line:

```
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

---

The issue is that you're passing the **command text** in the **SqlDataAdapter** constructor and the **@variable** parameter gets lost because it was added to **myCmd**.

---

Find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the change, however, it says I can no longer compile the program. Value of type "SqlCommand" cannot be converted to string

Comment: One of the SqlDataAdapter constructors is defined as **Public Sub New(selectCommand As SqlCommand)**. Did you remove the myConn.ConnectionString parameter? Which VB.NET version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would double check your SQL statement in SSMS to see if it is valid and returning what you expect. I passed the SQL statement and the connection to the constructor of the Command.

Although I left `.AddWithValue()`, it should really be the `.Add` method which includes the data type of the field.

When you use `DataAdapter.Fill()` it is not necessary to open the connection. If the connection is closed it will open and close it automatically but if the connection is open when `.Fill()` is called it will leave it open.

You are executing your query twice. Once with the myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery (it **is** a query, a Select statement, Insert, Update, Delete are non-queries). Then again with the `.Fill()`.

The `Using...End Using` statements ensure your objects that have a `.Dispose()` method are properly closed and disposed even if there is an error.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim strSQL As String = "select log_time as [Log Time], log_name as [Log Name], log_desc as [Log Description], type_name as [Log Type] from log as log
    left join log_type as lot on log.log_id=lot.type_id where type_name= @variable"
        Using myConn As New SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dwt-monitor;Trusted_Connection=True;")
            Using myCmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, myConn)
                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", Type)
                Using dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd)
                    table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
                    dataAdapter.Fill(table)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        dgvHardwareLog.DataSource = table
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myCmd.CommandText = "declare @variable as varchar(100) 
select log_time as [Log Time], log_name as [Log Name], log_desc as [Log Description], type_name as [Log Type] from log as log
left join log_type as lot on log.log_id=lot.type_id where type_name= @variable"
```

as you are using a variable, a variable must be declared, you haven't declared and that's the error. Declaration of variable will solve the error

Answer (score 0):

You're doing multiple forms of the same thing. The `Command` and `DataAdapter` both run queries so you only need one or the other depending on what you want to do with the data you retrieve.

I would fix your code as follows:

```
myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=dwt-monitor;Trusted_Connection=True;")

Dim qry as String = "select log_time as [Log Time], log_name as [Log Name], log_desc as [Log Description], type_name as [Log Type] from log as log
left join log_type as lot on log.log_id=lot.type_id where type_name= @variable"

Dim dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(qry, myConn)
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@variable", {your variable here})

'I assume Type is not an actual variable you have as I would think it would confuse the compiler from the keyword with the same name.
Dim table As New DataTable()

table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
dataAdapter.Fill(table)
dataAdapter.Dispose()

dgvHardwareLog.DataSource = table
```

I would also prefer `Using` statements over this way but did not want to change so much of your code that it wasn't recognizable.